Find learning rate for homomorphic encryption logistic regression model
I am implementing a homomorphic encryption logistic model using CKKS in SEAL library. To find the best learning rate and number of iterations, I use grid search on the normal logistic regression with unencrypted dataset and apply the parameters found. However, if in reality, I am only given an encrypted dataset without any additional information, how can I choose proper parameters for the FHE model?
Please suggest some methods for me in this case
